# List of TextViews in Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have a question about List in Listview,

what I want to achieve is to create a listView with multiple TextViews in each item(like another listview)
I don't know how many elements would be in each items

From what I know creating listview in listview is a bad idea

So I want to create a normal listview (with item1 / item 2 / item 3..) 
inside each row add linearlayout and populate it with textviews

I made this, but in every iteration it adds new linearlayout, how to change that? I want to add only textviews inside custom LinearLayout (R.layout.suplerowlist)

Or maybe is a better way to achieve that?

```
  @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    String menu_opcja = getItem(position);


    if (convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suplementacja_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.suplement = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_suplementu);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        ((LinearLayout) convertView).removeAllViews();

    }
    holder.suplement.setText(menu_opcja);

    for (int i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
        View holders = inflater.inflate(R.layout.suplerowlist, parent, false);
        TextView textViewTitles = (TextView) holders.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_supla);
        textViewTitles.setText(menu[i]);
         ((LinearLayout) convertView).addView(holders);
    }


    return convertView;

}
```

[image]

Comment: It sounds and looks like what you need is a ListView with sections/categories. Searching Google for "ListView with sections" gives several guides for this.

Comment: List view in the list view What about Expandable List view ?

Answer (score 0):

Using [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) would be the best solution for this type of situation see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) tutorial on how to use expandable list view.